# Symfony service only initiated after method call

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I noticed that a Symfony service is only initiated (the constructor is executed), when a method in that service is called. This can be important if your service only has a constructor, and no methods.

For example:

```
class MyService {

    public function __construct($someOtherService) {

        $someOtherService->setFoo("bar");

    }
}

// And of course put this service in services.yml

app.my_service:
    class: AppBundle\...\MyService
    arguments: [ app.some_other_service ]
```

In this case, the constructor and thus setFoo("bar") is not called. Why is this? Is it possible to somehow force the service to initiate, without calling a (dummy) method on this service?

I also tried to add "lazy: false" for the app.my_service, but that makes no difference.

I'm using Symfony 2.8.

Comment: You are misinterpreting something.  The constructor is called as soon as you get the service from the container.  Merely defining the service in services.yml does not cause the service to be instantiated.

Comment: Yes so I understand now. And I wanted to load the service without getting it from the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your services are never instantiated if they are never used. to enforce instantiating service you can hook into any kind of event listeners that suits your event, when you want get service (i.e `kernel.request`) and pass this service as a dependency to listener. this will trigger service constructor first time the event is triggered during the container lifespan.

but i'd rather suggest you to review the architecture. having service with the constructor only is nonsense

Moreover, you can instantiate services on instantiation of `EvendDispatcher` (just because it would depend on you service) without firing events

listener sample:

```
class ServiceInstantiatorListener
{
  public function onRequest(KernelEvent $kernel)
  {
     return; //noop, just make sure it works
  }

  public function instantiate($service)
  {
     return $service; // noop again, just call to pass service container argument
  }
}
```

yaml config:

```
services:
  my_app.service_instantiator_listener:
    class: My\App\ServiceInstantiatorListener
    tags:
    - { 'name': 'kernel_events', 'event': 'kernel.request', 'method':'onRequest' }
    calls:
    - [instantiate, ["@my_app.weird_service_one"]]
    - [instantiate, ["@my_app.weird_service_two"]]
```

Going further you can mark your services with tag and configurate calls dynamically with `MyAppBundleExtension` compiler passes

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#create-a-compiler-pass

I hope there are better ways to force instantiating services (i.e some container internal events), but currently I haven't met the case I need that.

Comment: Yes! I was already looking into using event listeners to find a solution. I understand what you mean, and I normally don't use services like this, but this is an edge case.

Comment: Thanks, I used your example to do it. Although I didn't use "instantiate", but as an argument I give the service container and in the listener I called both my two weird services ;)

Comment: Yes, but this delay instantiation until the event is fired, so depends on what you need

Answer (score 1):

You're describing the behaviour of a lazy-loaded service. Check the config for `lazy: true` and remove/disable it.

[Symfony docs, lazy loaded service:](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/lazy_services.html#configuration)

> The actual class will be instantiated as soon as you try to interact with the service (e.g. call one of its methods).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I already tried to add "lazy: false" for the app.my_service, but that did not work. I'll add it to my post.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to call a dummy method on the service to initiate it. 
You can instantiate the service object by using the following statement:

**$this->container()->get('app.my_service');**

Comment: This I knew, I wanted the service to load without that call.